# Draw text in OpenCV and save it to file. Showing Blank image

Tags: python, opencv

I am very new to opencv. Here I am trying to create an Image which will be a shape made of a string with 0's and 1's (The function random_shape generates that string). So the string is to be typed on top of a white background . Here I am able to create a White Background Image but unable to add text in front of it. It just creates a blank image. It also gives a segmentation fault if I give it different coordinates.
Any Help is Appreciated .

```
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX    
blank_image = np.zeros((100,100,3), np.uint8)                                                                    
cv2.putText(blank_image,random_shape(100,100),(0,0), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,(0,255,0))
blank_image[:,0:1*100] = (255,255,255)

image=cv2.cv.fromarray(blank_image)
cv2.cv.SaveImage('pic.jpg', image)
```

Update : I have changed my code to

```
blank_image = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
blank_image[:,0:512] = (255,255,255)
cv2.putText(blank_image,random_shape(100,100)[0:100],(0,0), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_\
SIMPLEX, 0.1,(0,0,0),cv2.CV_AA)
image=cv2.cv.fromarray(blank_image)
cv2.cv.SaveImage('pic.jpg', image)
```

[image]

It seems to be something garbled (its some sort of text with a line) instead of numbers. The size of the text also appears large.Any Help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can just save an image using `cv2.imwrite("filename.jpg", blank_image)`.

The docstring for `cv2.putText(...)` is:

`putText(img, text, org, fontFace, fontScale, color[, thickness[, lineType[, bottomLeftOrigin]]]) -> None`

The second argument of `cv2.putText`, "text", is a string. Chances are, `random_shape` in your code does not store "valid" characters. So you are passing values to `cv2.putText` that cannot be "translated" to proper characters that can be displayed.

Why don't you debug by manually specifying a string in place of the values obtained from `random_shape`? That way, you can test whether the problem is with your code or with the libraries that OpenCV uses print characters or write to the image file etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I needed to remove cv2.CV_AA and also in case of multiple lines of output there needs to be sufficient vertical spacing.

```
blank_image = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
blank_image[:,0:512] = (255,255,255)
cv2.putText(blank_image,random_shape(100,100)[0:100],(10,10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_\
SIMPLEX, 0.2,(0,0,0))
image=cv2.cv.fromarray(blank_image)
cv2.cv.SaveImage('pic.jpg', image)
```

I managed to create something like this adding the above code in a function. Need to work a bit more on it.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just do `cv2.imwrite("pic.jpg", blank_image)`?

Comment: Also, `cv2.putText(...)`'s second argument takes in a string. What is inside random_shape? Are they characters?

Comment: cv2.imwrite does help . The random_shape function gives a string for each row in the image. I just needed to create a random image made out of text.

Comment: Have you tried manually entering a string in place of using what is returned by random_shape? This will help you rule out the case where you libraries are not compiled properly. Also, print out what is returned by random_shape. Check OpenCV to see if putText handles unicode, and whether that is what random_shape is returning. Usually passing strings that cannot be translated to libs are what causes weird symbols to appear.